# Como escrever a data e hora de um erro no log do Django?

Tags: apache, django, log

Eu iniciei um projeto no Django 1.4, e todo erro que eu pegava via `try..except` eu imprimia no `sys.stderr` - fazendo ele cair no mesmo arquivo de log do Apache (error.log). Funcionava, mas só pros erros que eu explicitamente pegava, e além disso os erros de todas as instâncias em execução iam pro mesmo arquivo. Mas a vantagem é que o Apache prefixava todos os erros com a data e hora do erro.

Quando fiz upgrade pro Django 1.9, comecei a usar o sistema de *logging* baseando-me [nesse primeiro exemplo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.9/topics/logging/#examples) (no settings.py):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/statistics/logs/django_errors.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

E ele passou a logar no arquivo especificado todos os erros 500, inclusive os que eu não pegava explicitamente. O único problema é que ele só loga o erro em si, não dá nenhuma indicação da data e da hora do erro, nem nenhuma informação adicional:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/example/projeto/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 618, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'area' cannot be null")
```

Existe um jeito simples de logar a data e hora do erro, pra ficar mais fácil correlacionar com a entrada no access.log (onde é escrito algo como `"POST /meu/caminho HTTP/1.1" 500`)? Eu imagino que eu tenha de mexer no `formatters`, mas lendo a documentação não entendi muito bem como ele funciona. O mais importante pra mim é o *stack trace*, é claro, mas essa informação adicional seria muito útil (se não for possível, ou for algo mais complicado, posso viver sem isso - afinal esse tipo de erro é relativamente raro).

P.S. Estou usando mod_wsgi, se isso for de alguma relevância.

Comment: Isso pode te interessar responder: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191784/101, vou apagar aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu testei aqui e realmente não estava mostrando a data e hora, mas basta indicar o formato do log que funcionou, neste caso coloquei `formatter: 'verbose'`, esse `verbose` está formatado com a data:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '{0}/errors.log'.format(BASE_DIR),
            'formatter': 'verbose'  # aqui você indica o formato definido em formatters
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Eu atualmente utilizo sentry para organizar melhor os erros, uso o serviço [getsentry.com](https://getsentry.com), me atende bem e é bem fácil de usar, se não me engano permite até 200 erros por dia de forma gratuita.

Answer (score 0):

Peguei os dados dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220312/3517631):

A documentação oficial do logging é [essa](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter).

Exemplos:

```
# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s",
                              "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Aí você pode pegar na documentação os campos que você quiser e montar o log da melhor maneira.

**Atualizando:**

Esse eu usei em um sistema meu:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG, filemode="w", format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
```

Comment: Nessa pergunta o autor está criando um *logger* via código, para logar coisas também via código (tipo: `logger.error("mensagem")`). No meu caso eu estou definindo um *logger* no `settings.py` (desculpe se isso não ficou claro na pergunta), para que o próprio Django use. Eu vi na documentação do Django um exemplo parecido (`'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'`), mas não entendi muito bem o que isso significa no contexto do Django.